# Oultook 2016 does not show all Outlook.com Calendar Events when the calendars are overlayed

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016, outlook.com

I have an outlook.com email account that have 7 different calendars under that account to help me keep my families calendar's organized.  This account is used on my PC with Outlook 2016 and on my Samsung Galaxy phones.  I noticed tonight that not all the events are showing properly in Outlook.

I have run a quick and a full repair on Outlook.  I have create a new profile.  The problem still persists.

If I look on my phone, all the events show properly.  If I log into Outlook.com from a web browser, all the events show correctly.  If I look at each calendar individually (remove it from the overly), all the events show correctly.  If I overlay the calendars in Outlook 2016 some events do not show up.

This is where it gets really weird.  If the first calendar in the list does not have any events to display for the selected view (Week, month), then no other events from any other calendar are visible.  If the first calendar in the list has an event to display, sometimes all the other events from the other calendars will display properly.  Sometimes select events will not display.  I cannot find the pattern in this scenario on why some display and some do not.

I do not remember having seen this problem before.  Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed with build 8827.2179 per MS. Confirmed myself for what that's worth.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/calendar-overlay-does-not-show-appointments-for-additional-account-42b68057-f12f-4dd0-b11a-261359fc072d

It was just a bug with the last build.

Other Outlook bugs:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fixes-or-workarounds-for-recent-issues-in-Outlook-for-Windows-ecf61305-f84f-4e13-bb73-95a214ac1230?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US